Need raw text segregated into just title and content , from wikipedia dump (English)
I am working on a Full Text Search Implementation (sort of a matching algorithm) in a tool called Tantivy_py , I tried with a small text source and it worked smoothly , Now i want to test it on a very large text source , so I went ahead and downloaded the Wikipedia English Dump (xml) file . Uncompressed it's around 92 GB .
I want an only text file (.txt) which contains Title and Content of every page , I have no idea what the XML file looks like , because my laptop gives up even if i go somewhere near opening the 92 gb file.
I would like to know what is the possible way to extract this information from the xml dump , prefferably using python script or some library or cpp ...
If extracting info from the dump is the wrong way forward , please suggest the right way.

To help with your PC hanging, you can use head on linux and Get-Content or gc in windows powershell to get only enough data from the XML to see the format.
Everything else might be off topic here.
